# How to run a single line of python code in Visual Studio an get the output in Terminal?

Tags: python

I have a python code 'abc.py' an it has the below two input lines:

```
ALPHA = str(input("ENTER THE ALPHABET(A,B,C,D): "))  #A
BETA  = int(input("ENTER THE DIGIT: ")) #3

print(ALPHA)
print(BETA)
```

In visual studio when I run this code completely, it asks for input in terminal and executes.

But when I try to run the code line by line, I am not able to execute and it gives the below error:

```
input : The term 'input' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,   
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

How can I run the code line by line an keep getting the output for 'print' in terminal/output window?

I don't want to run the whole code everytime to get a output.

Currently the path prompt in my terminal shows the below. should it also have python to it?

```
PS C:\User\ABC\Desktop\test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter python to run a single line of python code.

[image]